# Trying to add data to database but getting "Error: Call to a member function save() on boolean"

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and I'm trying to add data to my coupon table with the following code.

In my UsersController I have:

```
public function addCoupon() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Coupon->save($this->request->data)) {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
}
```

In my add_coupon.cpt I have:

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Form->create('Coupon',['url' => ['action' => 'addCoupon']]);
 echo $this->Form->input('coupon_code');
 echo $this->Form->input('expiration_date');
 echo $this->Form->input('discount_amount');
 echo $this->Form->input('usage_limit');
 echo $this->Form->input('domain_limit');
 echo $this->Form->input('description');
 echo $this->Form->input('type');
 echo $this->Form->button('Submit');
 echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

If your model is, in fact, named `Coupon` (singular) rather than `Coupons` (plural), try adding the following line of code anywhere before `$this->Coupon->save(this->request->data)`:

```
$this->loadModel('Coupon');
```

But if it's actually named `Coupons` as convention would prescribe, change  `$this->Coupon->save(this->request->data)` to  `$this->Coupons->save(this->request->data)`
and add this line instead:

```
$this->loadModel('Coupons');
```

By default, the Users controller will only load the Users model. If you use any other models, you need to [load them manually](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel). Alternatively, you could move all of this to the Coupons controller, where it probably belongs anyways.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this solved part of the problem, but now I'm getting a different error. It's telling me: Error: Call to a member function errors() on array 
File /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/referral/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php 
Line: 1481 I'm a bit confused about this...